# Storing files on MongoDB through node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
var chatLogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    date: {unique: false,type: String},
    time: {unique: false,type: String},
    room: {unique: false,type: String},
    user_nick: {unique: false,type: String},
    user_message: {unique: false,type: String},
    user_file: {unique: false, type: Buffer}
});

delivery.on('receive.success', function(file) {
        var fsbuffer;
        var fd = __dirname + '\\public\\' + file.name;
        fs.writeFileSync(fd ,file.buffer);
        var ext = path.extname(file.name).slice(1);
        var buff = new Buffer(file.data.toString('base64'), 'base64');

chatLogModel.create({
              date: currentDate,
              time: currentHour,
              room: socket.room,
              user_nick: socket.username ,
              user_message: message,
              user_file: buff

          });
```

Here are some fragments of my code (I'm trying to write node.js live-chat application). There is no problem with saving files onto a hard drive, but i wanted to store them in the MongoDB. I don't want to use GridFS, since files uploaded will be 2-3MB at max, but trying to upload base64 strings like this causes problems when i upload files larger than 1KB. If I upload files smaller than 1KB then everything's works smoothly - after this limit, nothing is stored. I know i am doing something wrong, maybe the var buff contains wrong data, but I couldn't find the proper answer through google.

Comment: You're not handling database errors (by not passing a callback to `chatLogModel.create()`). You're also using `file.buffer` and `file.data` which doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: So what should i pass to user_file?